# Linking boost::locale with Embarcadero Berlin 10.1

Tags: c++, boost, linker, c++builder, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I've created a simple console application in Embarcadero Berlin 10.1, selected 32 bit clang compiler, and copied in some code from [here in the boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/locale/doc/html/hello_8cpp-example.html).

Here is the full code

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
  typedef char _TCHAR;
  #define _tmain main
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    using namespace boost::locale;
    using namespace std;
    generator gen;
    locale loc=gen("");
    // Create system default locale

    locale::global(loc);
    // Make it system global

    cout.imbue(loc);
    // Set as default locale for output

    cout <<format("Today {1,date} at {1,time} we had run our first localization example") % time(0)
      <<endl;

    cout<<"This is how we show numbers in this locale "<<as::number << 103.34 <<endl;
    cout<<"This is how we show currency in this locale "<<as::currency << 103.34 <<endl;
    cout<<"This is typical date in the locale "<<as::date << std::time(0) <<endl;
    cout<<"This is typical time in the locale "<<as::time << std::time(0) <<endl;
    cout<<"This is upper case "<<to_upper("Hello World!")<<endl;
    cout<<"This is lower case "<<to_lower("Hello World!")<<endl;
    cout<<"This is title case "<<to_title("Hello World!")<<endl;
    cout<<"This is fold case "<<fold_case("Hello World!")<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But I get some linker errors:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'boost::system::generic_category()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\18.0\LIB\WIN32C\RELEASE\LIBBOOST_LOCALE-BCB32C-MT-SD-1_55.LIB|generator
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'boost::system::system_category()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\18.0\LIB\WIN32C\RELEASE\LIBBOOST_LOCALE-BCB32C-MT-SD-1_55.LIB|generator
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'boost::locale::impl_win::create_convert(std::locale&, boost::locale::impl_win::winlocale&, unsigned int)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\18.0\LIB\WIN32C\RELEASE\LIBBOOST_LOCALE-BCB32C-MT-SD-1_55.LIB|win_backend
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'boost::locale::impl_win::create_collate(std::locale&, boost::locale::impl_win::winlocale&, unsigned int)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\18.0\LIB\WIN32C\RELEASE\LIBBOOST_LOCALE-BCB32C-MT-SD-1_55.LIB|win_backend
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'boost::locale::impl_win::create_formatting(std::locale&, boost::locale::impl_win::winlocale&, unsigned int)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\18.0\LIB\WIN32C\RELEASE\LIBBOOST_LOCALE-BCB32C-MT-SD-1_55.LIB|win_backend
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'boost::locale::impl_win::create_parsing(std::locale&, boost::locale::impl_win::winlocale&, unsigned int)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\18.0\LIB\WIN32C\RELEASE\LIBBOOST_LOCALE-BCB32C-MT-SD-1_55.LIB|win_backend
```

The first two I can fix by manually adding libboost_locale-bcb32c-MT-SD-1_55.lib to the project, it's my understanding and experience with boost that it shouldn't really need manually linking, but I don't mind this.  The last 4 however, I'm not sure about at all.  It looks to be related to the locale backend (Is it not ICU with Embarcadero supplied boost?)

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: http://icu-project.org/download/4.0.html has some windows sources also, there is a high probability that you will need to compile it for yourself.

Comment: It should still be able to use the winapi backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very interesting to me. So I created a new project and copied your code into it and sure enough the problem repeated itself.
After doing some research the only way I was able to overcome this issue was by adding `collate.cpp` and `converter.cpp` and `numeric.cpp` located in `$(BDSINCLUDE)\boost_1_55\libs\locale\src\win32` into my project.
I also had to add `#pragma link "libboost_system-bcb32c-mt-sd-1_55.lib"` into my source code before the `main` function.

Sam

Comment: I have changed the answer. I tested this and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had searched for the implementation of those functions but not thought to look in "include"... I'll remember this for next time.

Comment: @andyc You are very welcome. Just a thought, but you can also make a LIB from all the files in that directory and just include the LIB into your project, which I think would be a much cleaner approach.